# Hot to expand an existing shapefile

Tags: r, maps, tmap, arcmap, mapview

I got a small shapefile here: https://login.filesanywhere.com/fs/v.aspx?v=8c6d62875b6371b5a3ac . I need to make it a little bigger by adding a border above along the coast and another border in the ocean below along the coast. Ideally, I would like to do it using R but ArcMap or ArcMap pro are ok as well. I can also do it myself if someone is willing to share the steps in R or Arcmap.
I have not attempted anything because I have no idea where to start. See snapshot below:

```
library(mapview)
library(tmap) 
library(maps)
library(tidyverse)
myshape <- readRDS('bay.RDS')
```

[image]

Comment: It's not really about expanding but adding a section of a coastline from some other geospatial dataset that you have access to. You most likely already have the file, it's the one that your `myshape` subset was extracted from. If you don't care about level details, you could also just trace those few lines manually over a base map in any desktop GIS or with some online tool ( e.g. https://geojson.io/#map=9.53/38.2023/-122.9941 ) and load resulting shapes with `sf`.

Comment: geojson.io doesn't appear to have a freehand tool and I can only do a straight line. Will check others. Does any one know how to do this in ArcGis Pro?